# textbox controls are display the main page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have designed the basic controls application in asp.net.---> Using the 3 controls are display the choosing controls.---->controls are added on the dropdownbox.-----> Values are enter the textbox.-----> Click to the button.
I have click the button is to show on the choosing controls are displayed it.
i had attached the snapshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5NrZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correctly, you want to display appropriate asp.net control in a rectangle as displayed in the image?

Basically, I would go about it like this:

1. Add placeholder on main page. This placeholder will be used to store conrols.
2. Handle button click event in which you create desired controls and add them to placeholder

Main page addon:
`<asp:Placeholder runat="server" ID="phControls"></asp:Placeholder>`
and where button is, you need to add OnClick event handler
`<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAddControl" ... OnClick="btnAddControl_Click"></asp:Button>`

Main page code-behind:

```
...

protected void btnAddControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   if (myDropDown.SelectedValue == "TextBox") {
       var tb = new TextBox();
       tb.Text = tbEntry.Text;
       phControls.Controls.Add(tb);
   }
   ...
}
```

Something like that. Would prefer more information and some of your code though.